# How to program this game with basic C# and ASP .NET knowledge?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would love to brainstorm with you guys on how to program this game (originally a flash game) in C#. I'm studying C# right now and my knowledge is pretty limited: I know the pretty much the basics of C#  but I need your help with the concept.
Here's the game:
http://www.composica.com/product/samples/AstroHops/content/scaler.html
[alt text http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/5735/frogim3.jpg](http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/5735/frogim3.jpg)

I thought about using imagebutton for each lilypad that would trigger a modal window with question.
I also thought about placing a picture of a frog on each lilypad, set to visible = false. When the a certain lilypad is selected the frog's visibility will be set to true.

Any thoughts, ideas, suggestion on how to this better?
Maybe links to a similar game coded with c#?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marc solution seems like best one, but if you really need it in C# (in ASP.NET Right?) 
then you might consider AJAX but yea it is sort of bad approach.

If it is winforms you are talking about, then i would consider using some 2d graphics engine for that. otherwise your idea CAN work with the default .net forms, it just wont look very nice....

you might take a look at this, seems like a nice start point for working with directX and c#
http://www.csharp-home.com/index/tiki-print_article.php?articleId=146

Good luck with your project!

Comment: Esh, thanks for the answers! I think I won't be able to handle any more than a not-so-pretty 2d game. We hardly get anywehre directX in class.
Also, we only learned using web forms, but my guess is winforms are quite similar.
Thanks for the links!

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET (and HTML generally) isn't directly suited to compete with flash - they simply work differently. Perhaps look at [Silverlight](http://silverlight.net/); that is the MS offering that is closest to flash, and you can use C#.

Comment: Thanks,but the game itself should be written with C#.
Any thoughts?

Comment: C# is compatible with Silverlight

Comment: As I already said in the reply: you write Silverlight apps *in* C#. C# is a programming language - it can be used in lots of different platforms (winforms (exe/WPF), webforms (ASP.NET), silverlight, xbox (XNA), mobile devices (CF), robots (MF), etc).

Comment: I didn't know that, i'll check it out.